Flutter Update com.google.android.play
Today we received this message from google:
Update the Play Core Maven dependency to an Android 14 compatible version! The current Play Core library is incompatible with targetSdkVersion 34 (Android 14), which introduces a retroactive change to broadcast receivers to improve user security. As a reminder, as of August 31, Google Play requires all newly released apps to be compatible with Android 14. Update the dependency to the latest version of the Play Core library to avoid app crashes: https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore#playcore-migration
We tried following the guide and added the following dependencies to our app/build.gradle:
    dependencies {
     implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:2.0.1'
     implementation 'com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.2.2'
     implementation 'com.google.android.play:feature-delivery:2.1.0'
     implementation 'com.google.android.play:review:2.0.1'
     implementation 'com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0'
    }

Now when we try to launch the app via 'flutter run' we are returned the following error:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.

Manifest merge failed: Attribute meta-data#com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.versionCode@value value=(20202) from [com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.2.2] AndroidManifest.xml:26:17-38
is also present in [com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3] AndroidManifest.xml:38:17-38 value=(11003).
Tip: Add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to the  element in AndroidManifest.xml to override it.

What are we doing wrong?
Thank you very much

the question seems to be here, I'll put the same solution below
com.google.android.play:core might be a transitive dependency in your project, causing the conflict. To identify which dependency is using it, go to the android folder.
android cd

and run the following command
./gradlew app:dependencies > dependencies.txt

It will generate a text file, where you can see which dependency is using com.google.android.play:core.
In our case, it was a package that used the in_app_update package. So, we just overwrote the dependency in pubspec.
dependency_overrides:
 in_app_update: ^4.2.3

